# Rails 5 can't display image outside /app/assets/images directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

```
<%= image_tag("/public/pool_2.jpg") %>
```

it found the image, but there is no picture

I checked the assets.paths in rails console, and it does include "/public" directory in the assets.paths

```
rails c
```

> Rails.application.assets.paths

...

```
vice/home_service/public", ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I didn't move my carrierwave uploads to /public for some reason. I also changed in /config/application.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

and I doubled checked the value of config.public_file_server.enabled on rails console. But Rails 5 still doesn't like to display static images like /public/image.png.

So I just sub the "/app/assets/images" part out, then it works. Now the image is displayed.
Here is my hack:

```
<% @image_src = @profile.avatar.url(:thumb).sub(/\/app\/assets\/images\//, "")  %>
<%= image_tag @image_src %>
<%#= image_tag @profile.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing the image in /public/assets/images in order to mirror the structure of app/assets, for consistency's sake.

In your view, you could then use:

```
<%= image_tag '/assets/images/pool_2.jpg' %>
```

Also, be sure that `config.public_file_server.enabled` is set to `true` in config/application.rb.

You should review the [How to Use the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) section of the Asset Pipeline docs.

Comment: #add to config/application.rb
  `  config.public_file_server.enabled = true`
# try
`<%= image_tag "/public/pool_2.jpg" %>`
# got this error
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/pool_2.jpg"):`

Comment: # on my rails console

bundle :004 > Rails.application.config.public_file_server.enabled
 => true

Comment: @KieuHua Per my answer, have you moved the image and updated the path in your call to `image_tag`?